# Errors and unknown classes from bootstrap CDN

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm getting a lot of errors showing in the developer console, but they're all listed as coming from `maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Here are some of the errors listed:

```
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-inner-spin-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-search-cancel-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'width'.  Declaration dropped. 
Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'.  Declaration dropped. 
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. 
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
Expected end of value but found '�'.  Error in parsing value for 'line-height'.  Declaration dropped.
Unknown property 'user-select'.  Declaration dropped.
```

It's a personal site targeted to potential employers, so I don't want them to think I have errors in my website. Does anyone know why I'm getting these and how I can get rid of them?

Comment: were u able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with Firefox? Loading a blank html document with the link to bootstrap.min.css in Chrome doesn't indicate any errors in the console panel; in Firefox you get a bunch of errors.

Comment: It seems to be. I'm getting no errors in the chrome console either, but I like the debugging idea of loading bootstrap into a blank page. Will remember that.